# Able to connect to server with winscp but unable to connect with filezilla

Tags: ftp, winscp

I am unable to connect to the server with filezilla but with winscp I am able to connect. Both filezilla and winscp connect using port 22. Why is filezilla unable to connect to the server?

Comment: Any logfile entries on the server?

Comment: Hi, SvenW, there are alot of logfile in the server. Do i look at firewall logfile. Sorry. i just started touching server stuff. im a bit dumb.

Comment: Do you use sftp for filezilla connection?

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Yes. im using SFTP in filezilla connection. Filezilla error message : Error: Connection timed out
Error: Could not connect to server

Answer (score 2):

I am able to connect already. solution: Set timeout = 0 in filezilla. Apparently, my server needs more time to connect therefore setting timeout to 0 will prevent the connection to timeout.

Comment: Weird, WinSCP connects just fine for me in 17 secs, but FileZilla only connects when I make the timeout greater than the default 20 secs. This is on an IONOS server (formerly 1&1)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but in this case it was necessary to check "Bypass proxy" on the Site Manager/advanced tab. It was trying to use the proxy instead of a direct connection.